Solving an integral with various special cases
Let $y_k(x) = \int \frac{x^2}{x^4 + kx^2 + 1} dx$ be a family of curves and $\{S = \{ y_k(x)\} \mid k \in \mathbb{R} \}$. Then prove that all of the following family of curves appear in S:
(A) $\frac{1}{4} \ln \left| \frac{x^2 - x - 1}{x^2 + x - 1} \right| + \frac{1}{4\sqrt{5}} \ln \left| \frac{x^2 - \sqrt{5}x + 1}{x^2 + \sqrt{5}x + 1} \right| + C$
(B) $\frac{-x}{2x^2 - 2} + \frac{1}{4} \ln \left| \frac{x - 1}{x + 1} \right| + C$
(C) $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{x^2 - 1}{\sqrt{2}x} \right) + \frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}} \ln \left| \frac{x^2 - \sqrt{2}x + 1}{x^2 + \sqrt{2}x + 1} \right| + C$
(D) $\frac{1}{4} \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{x^2 - 1}{2x} \right) - \frac{x}{2x^2 + 2} + C$

What have you done so far? It looks pretty straightforward: show that A,B,C,D are all possible primitive functions of the integrand in the question for some value(s) of $;k;$ ....and show your own work if you still have any question.

Consider partial fraction decomposition.

@DonAntonio , oh I got it now. It struck me late but I got the answer . Should I delete this post ?

@rohit1729 Not necessary to delete this, someone might find this helpful, as I have.....

What you need to do is to differentiate each to see if the derivatives are of form $\frac{x^2}{x^4+kx^2+1}$.

as @xpaul rightfully suggested you can confirm all the four curves lie in $S$ by differentiating all four:
$$(A)\,\frac{1}{4} \ln \left| \frac{x^2 - x - 1}{x^2 + x - 1} \right| + \frac{1}{4\sqrt{5}} \ln \left| \frac{x^2 - \sqrt{5}x + 1}{x^2 + \sqrt{5}x + 1} \right|+c \implies \frac{x^{2}}{x^{4} - 3x^{2} + 1}$$

$$(B) \,\frac{-x}{2x^2 - 2} + \frac{1}{4} \ln \left| \frac{x - 1}{x + 1} \right| + C\implies \frac{x^{2}}{x^4-2x^2+1}$$

$$(C)\, \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{x^2 - 1}{\sqrt{2}x} \right) + \frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}} \ln \left| \frac{x^2 - \sqrt{2}x + 1}{x^2 + \sqrt{2}x + 1} \right| + C \implies \frac{x^{2}}{x^{4} + 1}$$

$$(D)\,\frac{1}{4} \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{x^2 - 1}{2x} \right) - \frac{x}{2x^2 + 2} + C \implies \frac{x^{2}}{x^4+2x^2+1}$$
So all four correspond to $k=-3,-2,0,2$

This is how I solved it:
$$y_k(x) = \int \frac{x^2}{x^4 + kx^2 + 1} dx$$
$$= {\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{x^2 +1}{x^4 + kx^2 + 1}dx} + {\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{x^2 -1}{x^4 + kx^2 + 1}} dx$$
$$ = {\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}{x^2+ k + \frac{1}{x^2}}dx} + {\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}{x^2+ k + \frac{1}{x^2}}dx}$$
Then we convert the denominator term into a square term by completing the square:
$$ ={\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}{({x- \frac{1}{x}})^2 +k+2}dx} + {\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}{({x+\frac{1}{x}})^2 +k-2}dx}$$
Note that $1+\frac{1}{x^2}$ is the derivative of ${x- \frac{1}{x}}$.
Similarly note that $1-\frac{1}{x^2}$ is the derivative of ${x+\frac{1}{x}}$.
Rest can be solved by substituting and by taking various cases for $k$.
PS: This method is called algebraic twins

I hate to be that guy, but is the term "algebraic twins" well-known in math? I couldn't find anything after Googling the term and that link seems sketchy because of the lack of LaTeX and how much the writer is trying to promote their tutoring through so much ads. :P

@Accelerator , you're correct. This may not be a very well known thing in math, it's very specific to integrals of this type
